# What should be the Bayes factor while testing a simple null against a composite alternative?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, bayesian, inference

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $\text{Poisson}(\theta)$ where $\theta$ has a Gamma prior. The testing problem is $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ against $H_1:\theta\ne \theta_0$. I am trying to find the Bayes factor in favour of $H_1$.

Let $\Theta_i$ be the parameter space under $H_i$ and $\Pi(\Theta_i)=\int_{\Theta_i}\pi(\theta)\,d\theta$ where $\pi$ is the prior density, $i=0,1$. Similarly, $\Pi(\Theta_i\mid \boldsymbol x)=\int_{\Theta_i}\pi(\theta\mid \boldsymbol x)\,d\theta$ where $\pi(\theta\mid \boldsymbol x)$ is the posterior density.

My definition of Bayes factor in favour of $H_1$ is $$B=\frac{\text{Posterior odds}}{\text{Prior odds}}=\frac{\Pi(\Theta_1\mid \boldsymbol x)/\Pi(\Theta_0\mid \boldsymbol x)}{\Pi(\Theta_1)/\Pi(\Theta_0)}=\frac{\Pi(\Theta_1\mid \boldsymbol x)/\Pi(\Theta_1)}{\Pi(\Theta_0\mid \boldsymbol x)/\Pi(\Theta_0)}$$

For simple null against simple alternative, say $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ vs $H_1':\theta=\theta_1(\ne \theta_0)$, Bayes factor is the likelihood ratio:

$$B=\frac{\pi(\theta_1\mid \boldsymbol x)/\pi(\theta_1)}{\pi(\theta_0\mid \boldsymbol x)/\pi(\theta_0)}=\frac{f(\boldsymbol x\mid \theta_1)}{f(\boldsymbol x\mid \theta_0)}$$

But how to use this definition for simple versus composite alternative as I have in the problem above?

Do I have to use a mixture prior for $\theta$ like $$\pi(\theta)=p\delta_{\theta_0}+(1-p)g(\theta)\,,$$ where $\delta_{\theta_0}$ denotes a degenerate distribution at $\theta_0$ and $g(\cdot)$ is the pdf of a Gamma distribution on $\Theta-\{\theta_0\}$? If this is the case, should the Bayes factor be modified as

$$B=\frac{\Pi(\Theta_1\mid \boldsymbol x)/\Pi(\Theta_1)}{\pi(\theta_0\mid \boldsymbol x)/\pi(\theta_0)}=\frac{\Pi(\Theta_1\mid \boldsymbol x)/\Pi(\Theta_1)}{f(\boldsymbol x\mid \theta_0)}\,\,?$$

I guess the posterior would also be a mixed distribution if I go down this road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in [our reassessment](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1263478373) of his [1939 Theory of Probability](https://amzn.to/2VeReBk), this issue is central to Jeffreys' introduction of the Bayes factor (although an earlier version appears in Haldane, 1932, and Wrinch and Jeffreys, 1921, see [Etz & Wagenmakers, 2017](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1494489818)).

When considering a point null hypothesis such as $\text{H}_0: \theta=\theta_0$, the prior $\pi$ (if at all available before considering this null hypothesis) need be modified to incorporate a point mass at $\theta_0$. Otherwise, there is no need for data to reach a decision: $\text{H}_0$ is a priori and a posteriori impossible. This was made quite clear in Jeffreys' [1939 Theory of Probability](https://amzn.to/2VeReBk).

Using the (mixture) prior with the point mass at $\theta_0$
$$\pi^\prime(\theta)=p\delta_{\theta_0}+(1-p)\pi(\theta)$$
means that the null hypothesis is a priori possible, with a prior probability of
$$\Pi^\prime(\Theta_0) = \Pi^\prime(\{\theta_0\}) = p$$
The Bayes factor then writes as
$$\dfrac{\Pi^\prime(\Theta_1\mid \boldsymbol x)/\Pi^\prime(\Theta_1)}{\Pi^\prime(\Theta_0\mid \boldsymbol x)/\Pi^\prime(\Theta_0)} = 
\dfrac{\Pi^\prime(\Theta_1\mid \boldsymbol x)/(1-p)}
{\Pi^\prime(\Theta_0\mid \boldsymbol x)/p} =
\dfrac{\int_0^\infty f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta)\,\text d\theta}{f(x|\theta_0)} $$
and the posterior is indeed a mixture of a Dirac mass at $\theta_0$ and of a Gamma (continuous) distribution.